# scala loop through a linkedlist

Tags: scala

In scala, what is a good way to loop through a linked list(scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList) of objects? For example, I want to have 'for' loop traverse through each object on the linked list and process it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With foreach:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val ll = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int](1,2,3)
ll: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3)

scala> ll.foreach(i => println(i * 2))
2
4
6
```

or, if your processing of each object returns a new value, use map:

```
scala> ll.map(_ * 2)                  
res3: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(2, 4, 6)
```

Some people prefer *for comprehensions* instead of `foreach` and `map`. They look like this:

```
scala> for (i <- ll) println(i)
1
2
3

scala> for (i <- ll) yield i * 2
res5: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Why every body skipping fold? ll.foldLeft(0) {_ + _}

Comment: I thought even map was more than what @NullPointer0x00 was after. My interpretation of his question was that he wanted to perform a side-effect for each member of the collection. But you are right. foreach for side-effects, map for 1:1 or 1:* transformations and fold/reduce for *:1 transformations.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on the previous answer...
for, foreach and map are all higher-order functions - they can all take a function as an argument, so starting here:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list.foreach(i => println(i * 2))
```

You have a number of ways that you can make the code more declarative in nature, and cleaner at the same time.

First, you don't really need to use the name - `i` - for each member of the collection, you can use `_` as a placeholder instead:

```
list.foreach(println(_ * 2))
```

You can also separate the logic out into a distinct method, and continue to use placeholder syntax:

```
def printTimesTwo(i:Int) = println(i * 2)
list.foreach(printTimesTwo(_))
```

Even cleaner, just pass the raw function without specifying parameters (*look ma, no placeholders!*)

```
list.foreach(printTimesTwo)
```

And to take it to a logical conclusion, this can be made cleaner still by using *infix* syntax.  Which I show here working with a standard library method. *Note: you could even use a method imported from a java library, if you wanted*:

```
list foreach println
```

---

This thinking extends to anonymous functions and *partially-applied functions* and also to the map operation:

```
// "2 *" creates an anonymous function that will double its one-and-only argument
list map { 2 * }
```

For-comprehensions aren't really very useful when working at this level, they just add boilerplate.  But they do come into their own when working with deeper nested structures:

```
//a list of lists, print out all the numbers
val grid = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
grid foreach { _ foreach println } //hmm, could get confusing
for(line <- grid; cell <- line) println(cell) //that's clearer
```

I didn't need the `yield` keyword there, as nothing is being returned.  But if I wanted to get back a list of Strings (un-nested):

```
for(line <- grid; cell <- line) yield { cell.toString }
```

With lots of generators, you'll want to split them over multiple lines:

```
for {
  listOfGrids <- someMasterCollection
  grid <- listOfGrids
  line <- grid
  cell <- line
} yield {
  cell.toString
}
```